# In react, Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect

**Login.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import * as actions from "../actions/Login";
import { Link as RRDLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Copyright(props) {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
                Rishi
            </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const theme = createTheme();

const SignInSide = ({ ...props }) => {

    //toast msg.
    const { addToast } = useToasts()

    let history = useHistory();

    const [rememberme_checked, setRememberme_Checked] = useState(false);

    const onSuccess = () => {
        formik.resetForm();
        if (rememberme_checked)
            setRememberme_Checked(!rememberme_checked)
    };

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {                       
            username: '',
            password: '',
            rememberme: false
        },
        validationSchema: yup.object({                
            username: yup.string().max(20, 'UserName should not exceed 20 characters').required('Please Enter UserName'),
            password: yup.string().required('No password provided.').min(8, 'Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.').matches(/[a-zA-Z]/, 'Password can only contain Latin letters.'),
        }),
        onSubmit: values => {
            props.login(values, onSuccess);
        }
    });

    const handleCheckbox = () => setRememberme_Checked(!rememberme_checked);

    const mounted = useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        if (mounted.current) {
            console.log('login with ' + JSON.stringify(props.loginList))
            props.loginList.map((record, index) => {
                if (record.login_successful) {
                    addToast("Login successful", { appearance: 'success', autoDismiss: true })
                    history.push('/Home')
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem("authValue", true);
                    record.login_successful = false;
                }
                else {
                    addToast("Login Failed. Please try again with valid credentials", { appearance: 'error', autoDismiss: true })
                    window.localStorage.removeItem("authValue");
                }
            })
        }        
        return () => (mounted.current = false);        
    }, [props.loginList])

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Grid container component="main" sx={{ height: '100vh' }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={false}
                    sm={4}
                    md={7}
                    sx={{
                        backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
                        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                        backgroundColor: (t) =>
                            t.palette.mode === 'light' ? t.palette.grey[50] : t.palette.grey[900],
                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                        backgroundPosition: 'center',
                    }}
                />
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            my: 8,
                            mx: 4,
                            display: 'flex',
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                            <LockOutlinedIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                            Sign in
                        </Typography>
                        <Box component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="username"
                                label="User Name"
                                name="username"
                                autoComplete="username"
                                
                                {...formik.getFieldProps("username")}
                            />
                            {formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username ?
                                <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formik.errors.username}</span> : null}
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                name="password"
                                label="Password"
                                type="password"
                                id="password"
                                autoComplete="current-password"
                                {...formik.getFieldProps("password")}
                            />
                            {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password ?
                                <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formik.errors.password}</span> : null}
                            <br />
                            <FormControlLabel                                
                                control={<Checkbox name="rememberme" color="primary" onClick={handleCheckbox} checked={rememberme_checked} value={formik.values.rememberme}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange} />}
                                label="Remember me"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                            >
                                Sign In
                            </Button>
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item xs>
                                    <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>                                                                            
                                        <RRDLink to="/Learning">
                                            Don't have an account? Sign Up
                                        </RRDLink>                                                                                                                                         
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Copyright sx={{ mt: 5 }} />
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loginList: state.login.login
})

const mapActionToProps = {
    login: actions.post
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(SignInSide);
```

So, from login.jsx I want to set sessionStorage value which is authValue within the useEffect hook. But I am getting **Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**. I am using this sessionStorage in App.js to redirect based on the authValue when page is refreshed. I have tried number of approaches but couldn't fix this issue. Can anyone help me to fix this issue. Below is the App.js component

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useState, useEffect, Suspense, lazy } from "react";

const Login = lazy(() => import('./components/Login'));
const Learning = lazy(() => import('./components/Learning'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('./components/HomePage'));
/*const NotAuthorized = lazy(() => import('./components/URLPage'));*/

const App = ({ ...props }) => {
    let authValue = props.auth;
    let authR = false;
    if (window.performance) {
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            authR = window.sessionStorage.getItem("authValue");
            if (authR) {
                authValue = true;
            }
        } 
    }
        
    let routes = (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Learning" component={Learning} />
            <Route path="/" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    );

    if (authValue) {
        routes = (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/Home' component={Home} exact />
                <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                <Redirect to='/' />
            </Switch>
        );
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <div className="container px-3 mx-auto">
                    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>{routes}</Suspense>
                </div>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>

    );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loginlist: state.login.login,
    auth: state.login.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

Comment: you can remove `if (rememberme_checked)
            setRememberme_Checked(!rememberme_checked)`

Comment: @HMR It didn't work.